# Dynamically create variables in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of images that I am repeatedly calling the same functions for:

```
first_image = load_image("test1.jpg")
first_image_encoding = pic_encoding(first_image)[0]

second_image = load_image("test2.jpg")
second_image_encoding = pic_encoding(second_image)[0]
```

After which I need to populate them into an array like this:

```
encoding_arr = [
    first_image_encoding, 
    second_image_encoding
]
```

I am trying to do all of this dynamically but need help with the first part for assigning unique variable names to assigned values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
    for f in files:
        first_image = load_image(f)
        first_image_encoding = pic_encoding(first_image)[0]
```

I am not sure how to get a list of unique variables here instead of manually hard coding them

Comment: Why do you think you need to load them into separate variables? Just use a list.

Comment: no interest to name them; make a list :  image.append(load (image(f))).... You will retrieve them latter.

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is almost never the right way to do things. Use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating variables dynamically adds excessive overhead of handling them, instead you could directly append to list like so:

```
encoding_arr = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
    for f in files:
        encoding_arr.append(pic_encoding(load_image(f))[0])
```